# Get field data when using Spout to read an Excel file

Tags: laravel, spout

I'm using Spout to read an Excel file. Here is what my Excel looks like:

[image]

I tried doing this with some basic code from the Spout documentation:

```
$filePath = '/Users/nhathao/Desktop/employee-test.xlsx';
    $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
    //$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
    $reader->open($filePath);

    foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($row->getCells());
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
```

When I run that, I get the following data from the cells:

[image]

Is there any way to access these fields? Could I use something like $row->email? I want to get that value and store it in a variable to compare it with my value in database.

Hope you can help me!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$row->getCells` returns an array of `Cells`. You can access the value of each cell by calling `$cell->getValue()` on it.

In your case, if you want the email field, there's no magic mapping. If the email column is the 5th column, then you can do:

```
$cells = $row->getCells();
$emailCell = $cells[4]; // 4 because first column is at index 0.
$email = $emailCell->getValue();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Or we can use $cell[4]->value for shorter. I found this last night. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Another shorthand is:  `$row->getCellAtIndex(4)->getValue()`

Answer (score 5):

You can get value simply converting a row to an array. Assume you want to get the value of name. As you see the index of name is 1. What you have to do is:

```
foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $value = $row->toArray();
        $name = $value[1];
    }
}
```

Hope it'll help you.